# Compare a date and a timestamp with time zone with now() in the same query?

Tags: postgresql, datatypes, timestamp, date-format

I have multiple database servers I'm querying with a query that compares an expiration column with `now()`. The problem is that one of the servers' expiration column is a `timestamp with time zone`, and all the rest are simply `date`. I can't change this because I don't have admin access, and in fact I'm only querying the view. Postgres is fairly new to me, so I don't really understand how the dates and times work with each other.

When I try and query the server with `timestamp with time zone` by casting the `timestamp` as a `date`:

```
...
WHERE
    (
        status_code = '30000'
        OR status_code = '30005'
    )
AND CAST(expiration AS DATE) > now()
```

It works, but using the same query on the servers where `expiration` is already a `date` fails:

> [Err] ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type date: "No End Date"

Any help would be appreciated, I'd really rather not hard code an exception for this one DB server.

Comment: Are you sure `expiration` is a `timestamp` column? Sounds like it's a convertion problem caused by the `CAST` operator

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should **never** raise an exception with an actual `date` value:

```
...
WHERE status_code IN ('30000','30005')
AND   expiration > now()
```

PostgreSQL can compare [`date` and `timestamp` (with or without time zone)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) automatically. If one is a `date` it is cast to `timestamp` assuming '00:00' hours.

The error message tells a different story. You are actually trying to input a `date` with invalid syntax.

About handling timestamps with or without time zone in PostgreSQL:

- [Ignoring timezones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9576170/939860)

---

As it turns out, your `expiration` is a column of type `text`. You need to cast it to `date` or `timestamp` (whichever fits your need). For valid format:

```
...
AND   expiration::timestamptz > now()
```

Invalid strings like 'No End Date' in that text column need to be cleaned or treated specially in a `CASE` construct. Like:

```
...
AND   CASE expiration
         WHEN 'No End Date' THEN 'infinity'::timestamp
         WHEN 'foo'         THEN '-infinity'::timestamp
         ELSE expiration::timestamp
      END > now()
```

The manual about the special value [`infinity`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-SPECIAL-TABLE).

If the format of the timestamp literal can be ambiguous, use [`to_date()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#id-1.5.8.14.4.2.2.4.1.1.1) or [`to_timestamp()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#id-1.5.8.14.4.2.2.6.1.1.1) and define the format explicitly:

```
to_date('07/08/2013', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
to_timestamp(expiration, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

- [How to convert “string” to “timestamp without time zone”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18913236/how-to-convert-string-to-timestamp-without-time-zone/18919571#18919571)

Use the [`AT TIME ZONE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT) construct if `expiration` is supposed to be a local timestamp of a given time zone:

```
expiration::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'  -- desired time zone here
```

Comment: I get the following error with your query: [Err] ERROR:  operator does not exist: text > timestamp with time zone. This was my original query on all databases until I ran into this original error when querying this one machine with expiration stored as a timestamp+timezone. I'm also querying a view, does the view convert datatypes to text or something?

Comment: @Chris: I added a bit to my answer.